# how to open a WPF dialog from a WinForms menu

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WinForms menuitem and I need that on menu click the new WPF dialog is loaded.
How do I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to display it by creating a new instance of the WPF class for the dialog, and then calling its [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method.

The only trick is properly setting the owner of the WPF dialog. You can't just set the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property directly, since that requires a WPF window. However, you can use the class [System.Windows.Interop.WindowInterpHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) to get around this:

```
MyWpfDialog dialog = new MyWpfDialog();
new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(dialog).Owner = this.Handle;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

(I got the code sample from http://blog.stpworks.com/archive/2009/07/02/setting-wpf-dialog-owner-from-within-winforms-application.aspx.)